Compare Values in an SSRS Matrix
See the screenshot. I work in a school and have a pile of attainment data in my MIS. Each subject has a baseline predicted grade in row where the AspectShortName is "YellVA". There are up to three other Aspects called ATP1, ATP2, ATP3 for example. I need to be able to compare each of those AspectValues with the YellVA aspect to show how a student is in each subject at each attainment point (ATP - Academic Tracking Point). I can't for the life of me work out how to do it.
Hopefully the image has enough information in it.
Thanks
Kevin



You'll need to supply some sample data (in the format it appears from your dataset query) and your expected outcome. It's not clear (to me at least) what you are trying to do or what your data looks like.

@AlanSchofield I hope that helps.

You need to post sample data as text, there is no way anyone is going to retype all that to try to reproduce your issue. You also need to provide the expected results based on that same sample data so we can understand what you are trying to do and explain any logic that isn't really obvious. Read these two posts, which might help you write your question. How to Ask a good question and Why should I not upload images of data
